# wordpress viagra hack in header

Tags: wordpress, security

I can see a hack in the header of my Wordpress site for viagra in a hidden div but I don't know where to remove it. I have looked at some of the php files but I can't see code. I can see the hack on a mobile (android) and firefox.

[see website](http://www.global-markets-recruitment.com/)

Comment: can you please provide link ?

Comment: I have provided a link above

Comment: The code in your php may be encoded in base64 instead of plain text. So you may want to search for `base64_decode1`. http://us1.php.net/base64_decode. Wild guess though

Comment: where would i search for that?

Comment: If you have a backup use it. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Just search your whole web directory.

Comment: This hack tag is the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

Look everywhere. If one file has been compromised, then there's no reason to suppose that your other files are all safe.

Your best bet is to delete WordPress entirely, check your database *thoroughly* for content added by the hackers, change all your passwords (including site admin, MySQL and FTP) and then reinstall WordPress over the same database. But this time, be very careful when choosing themes and plugins. It's really not uncommon for nice-looking WordPress themes to have gaping security flaws.

For what it's worth, [here's a PHP script that I wrote to disinfect a site with a similar problem](http://ruletheweb.co.uk/blog/2013/04/php-malware/). It may not work on your site, but it should give you some idea of what to look out for.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I would take to find and eliminate this:

1. Look in the header.php file of your theme. This would be /wp-content/themes/child/header.php. In particular, look just below the body class and comment out any functions or PHP code you might find directly below this to see if there is a malicious function being called. The body tag probably looks like this:

   <body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
2. Deactivate all plugins on the site and check to see if the problem still persists. If it doesn't, then enable the plugins one by one until you find the culprit.
3. It looks like maybe they could be hooking into the body_class filter. Run a text search across all of your template files for a body_class filter, which will look like this:

   add_filter( 'body_class', 'filter_function_name' )

You'll want to search for **add_filter( 'body_class** and **add_filter('body_class** to catch possible differences in the whitespace.

Hopefully you'll find something.